# Extract part of string based on the value of another

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, substring, extract

I want to extract part of a string based on the condition on another string in another cell in a large datset.
I have:

```
V1                 V2
Tom Cruise         Tom Cruise (movie 1), Al Pacino (movie 2), Johnny Depp (movie 5)
Johnny Depp        Tom Bennet (movie 3, movie 4), Johnny Depp (movie 5)
Emma Watson        Al Pacino (movie 8), Emma Watson (movie 1, movie 3), Antony B. (movie 5)
```

And I need to create a new field based on V1 and that will report the text between parenthesis next to the name from V1. The resulting dataset would need to have:

```
V1                 V2                                                                           V3
Tom Cruise         Tom Cruise (movie 1), Al Pacino (movie 2), Johnny Depp (movie 5)             movie 1
Johnny Depp        Tom Bennet (movie 3, movie 4), Johnny Depp (movie 5)                         movie 5
Emma Watson        Al Pacino (movie 8), Emma Watson (movie 1, movie 3), Antony B. (movie 5)     movie 1, movie3
```

I tried a combination of function =LEFT and FIND but I sill get error.

```
=LEFT(V1, FIND( " (", V2))
```

Comment: Your second sample is the same as the first.

Comment: Beware that you can, depending on your dataset, get unwanted results when a certain name can be a substring of a longer name. Just `FIND` is not going to be faul-proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `C2` formula copied down :

```
=MID(B2,FIND(A2,B2)+LEN(A2)+2,FIND(")",B2,FIND(A2,B2))-FIND("(",B2,FIND(A2,B2))-1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An ugly one-step formula (could be a beautiful solution) is:

```
=MID(B2,FIND("), "&A2&" (","), "&B2)+LEN(A2)+2,FIND(")",B2,FIND("), "&A2&" (","), "&B2)+1)-FIND("), "&A2&" (","), "&B2)-LEN(A2)-2)
```

But usually for a case like this, it is better to use regular expression to help...

First, you need to prepare the regular expression VBA function. In VBA Reference, add "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expression 5.5". Then add this to some .xlam file that you will keep using as Excel plugin, or put locally in the .xlsm workbook.

```vb
Public ThisRE As New RegExp

Public Function ReplaceRE(ByVal FromStr As String, ByVal PatternStr As String, ByVal ByStr As String) As String
'$1 as first bracket
    ThisRE.Pattern = PatternStr
    ThisRE.Global = True
    ReplaceRE = ThisRE.Replace(FromStr, ByStr)
End Function
```

Formula to use regular express is:

```
=ReplaceRE(B3,"^.*(^|, )"&A3&" \(([^)]+)\).*","$2")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly more robust approach in terms of avoiding sub-string match issue which assumes your data is as consistent as you have shown.

`=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(V2,V1&" (",REPT(" ",99)),99,99)),")",REPT(" ",99)),99))`

change V1 and V2 as per actual layout.